# C# TAPI Lines and accepting calls

Tags: c#, tapi

So I'm creating an automated program that is making calls, and upon pickup is transferring them to another number. Making the call is fine - however the phone then goes into CS_OFFERING, and I can't seem to pick up the phone from my program at this point so the call can be connected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From my  experience, all you have to do is create a call on the address you want the call to be picked up with. Make sure to call the CreateCall-Method with a null pointer to the destination address.

After that, you should be able to call the Pickup-Method with the diable address of the line you want the call to pick up from as your group id.

```
ITBasicCallControl bcc = targetAddress.CreateCall(null, TapiConstants.LINEADDRESSTYPE_PHONENUMBER, TapiConstants.TAPIMEDIATYPE_AUDIO);
bcc.Pickup(sourceAddress.DialableAddress);
```

In my case, targetAddress is the address want the call to be placed on, after the pick up operation is completed. sourceAddress is the address the call originally was placed on.

Edit:
this only applies, if you're using TAPI 3.x, which, based on your call state CS_OFFERING, I think you are.